# php with sudo works on command line but not in browser

Tags: php, html, exec

Hello I am writing a little php/html page and trying to pass user & password to run, although it works on command line, it does not work in the browser.. Any advise?

```
$user = "echo password!";

$row = exec('$user | sudo -u user_id -S /usr/bin/VBoxManage list vms',$output,$error); 

echo "\n";

while(list(,$row) = each($output)){
    echo sprintf($row) . "<BR>\n"; 
}

if($error){
    echo "Error : $error<BR>\n"; exit; 
}
```

Comment: You should check if your php.ini file allows running the exec function. The exec function should not be present in the disable_functions configuration

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is that the sudo binary requires a full path too.

However, your syntax is incorrect - single quotes prevent `$user` from being expanded.

Even then, it is possible that `exec` will not honor the pipe request and you will instead need to authorize the user running Apache to issue VBoxManage commands without password, using `visudo`. Or you may want to look into `proc_*` functions.

This *should* work:

```
 $output = shell_exec("/bin/sh -c '{$user} | sudo -u ...'");
```